# PowerShell kill multiple process ids using an array

Tags: powershell

I tried multiple ways to kill PIDs using an array but unable to do so. If I use `echo` command instead of `taskkill` it works fine however if I use `taskkill` command I get the error as attached...
Also tried to convert `Array` datatype to `Int32` but still no success.

```
$a = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'powershell.exe' and commandLine like '%cycle%'" | Select-Object  ProcessId)
if ($a )
{
   taskkill.exe /F /PID $a[0]
   taskkill.exe /F /PID $a[1]
   taskkill.exe /F /PID $a[2]
}
```

**Error:**
[image: Error]

Comment: Try replacing your select-object statement with: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId` instead. This will only show the PID value, which is an int32. After you run that, you can do `$a | Get-Member` to see what else you are able to convert it to.

Answer (score 0):

Append `.ProcessId` to the end of the `$a` variable value since you have it enclosed in parenthesis already to list only the `ProcessId` numbers that match in the array without a column header value. Then pipe the matching `$a` array over to a `ForEach-Object` loop to iterate the `ProcessId` array values from it to the `taskkill` command to kill processes accordingly.

### PowerShell

```
$a = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'powershell.exe' and commandLine like '%cycle%'" | Select-Object  ProcessId).ProcessId;
$a | ForEach-Object {taskkill.exe /F /PID $_};
```

> **The issue** you are having is because using this code
>
> ```
> @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'powershell.exe' and commandLine like '%cycle%'" | Select-Object  ProcessId)
> ```
>
> Gives this output which contains the header column which `taskkill` cannot interpret.
>
> ```
> ProcessId
> ---------
>     2244
> ```
>
> **Using this code**
>
> ```
> @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'powershell.exe' and  commandLine like '%cycle%'" | Select-Object  ProcessId).ProcessId
> ```
>
> Gives this output which is only the `int` values of the matching
> processes which `taskkill` can use to process/kill accordingly.
>
> `2244`
>
> **Note:** Using `$_.ProcessId` with your existing code may work the way you have it written to expand at that level so `taskkill.exe /F /PID $_.ProcessId` may also suffice. I do not believe the conditional `if()` is needed at all though so I'd omit it.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)